# Adding columns in pandas df with boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
Test  Test2  Test3
a     d      1
b     d      4
a     s      5
a     d      2
```

I want to write a function that looks at all the rows and if the values in Test and Test2 are the same, it adds all the values in Test3 and creates this as a new row and deletes all the old ones with duplicates in Test and Test2.
In this case, the final df would look like this:

```
Test  Test2  Test3
a     d      3
b     d      4
a     s      5
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through the df and deleting all the rows "manually"?

How would I handle additional columns using the code in the suggested post?

Comment: `How would I handle additional columns using the code in the suggested post?` can you be more specific?

Comment: @jezrael When making the minimal example, I did not know that it would make a difference how many other columns there are. For example, I have two others and if I use the code in the other post, they are cut away.

Comment: hmmm, I think reason is there are no numeric, the best is create better sample data with expected output